# Searching for Computer Name based on x number of characters

Tags: powershell

I am trying to search for computer name and search the name based on comparing 6-8 characters of the name and then move it to the respective OU. I believe regular expressions need to be included but I need help. Please advise

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Force
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
#$computername = gc env:computername
$computername = "vststsystest01"
#if ($env:computerName.contains("APP")) {Write-Host $env:computerName}
if ($computername.contains(" ") | Get-ADComputer $computername | Move-
ADObject -Targetpath "ou=ou_name,dc=DC,dc=cient,dc=com"
```

Need to look at the characters in the name vststsystest01 - 6-8 characters should be searched for. For example, if it contains SYS then move it to a respective OU.

Comment: Are you trying to get a single computer object? Or retrieve all computer objects with that string in the name?

Comment: Do you have several matches to ous you have to work with? A `switch` block might be what you want here.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your post. You can delete it instead

Comment: What makes this vandalism even worse is that you got multiple good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your last edit :

```
$computername = "vststsystest01"

if($computername.substring(5,3) -match "Sys|Sec|App"){
    Get-ADComputer $computername | Move-ADObject -Targetpath "ou=ou_name,dc=DC,dc=cient,dc=com"
}
```

Comment: awesome, what is substring(5,3) -?

Comment: @HenryB It starts at character 5 in the string and captures 3 characters.  It's a string object method

Comment: SYS can appear 6-8 characters in the name, not at a specified character position

Comment: You can take a look at this : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692804.aspx for string methods

Comment: can you update it to search for 6-8 characters instead of just the 5th?

Comment: @HenryB Strings are 0-indexed.  Position 5 is character 6.  I've updated my answer

Comment: got it but any way to search character 6-8?

Comment: @HenryB This requirement is starting to confuse people. Can you show us some example of strings that should match and ones that dont. I think what the answer here is trying to do is what you want. Are you saying that the string sys could _start_ at character position 6-8? abdefsys and abcdefsys are both matches?

Answer (score 3):

Edit: I mistook OP's contains statement for an array collection.  He actually was using it on a single string which [looks for the specified string and returns `$True` if it is indeed a substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx)

I believe you're looking for the [`-like` comparison operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-5.1)

```
If ($ComputerName -like '*vs2016*')
{
    Get-ADComputer $ComputerName | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $Path
}
```

---

Update:

If you're trying to search for specific characters that are constant in the hostname, you can use `.Substring()` to access them and the regex OR `|` operator.  Alternatively, I think you should utilize the `switch` statement.

```
## Substring(5,3) captures 3 characters starting at position 5 (6th character)
Switch ($ComputerName.Substring(5,3))
{
    'SYS' { <# logic #> }
    'TIT' { <# logic #> }
    'TAT' { <# logic #> }
    Default { <# catch-all if it doesn't match #> }
}
```

Comment: that name is not being used. look at computer name vststsystest01

Specifically you are looking at characters 6-8 which in this case are sys.  It could be one of the following sets of characters just to name a few.

Sys
Sec
App
etc
Based on these sets of characters it would move the machine to a corresponding OU

Comment: I gave you the tools based on your example.  Figure out the logic on your own. @HenryB

Comment: edited the original question thank you

Comment: @Matt I made the assumption he had an array of strings he was trying to use `.Contains()` with.  I'll update my answer since his question is updated.

Comment: @Matt Updated with a link to documentation

Comment: thank you but appears Manu's approach has worked